# How to send a message to friends inbox through fbconnect api or fbgraph api?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk, fbconnect

I want to ask that how to send message to a friend's inbox in Facebook through Facebook Connect API or Facebook graph API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use a send dialog. It works like the Feed Dialog (that will post to the wall) but it prompts the user to select one or more friends and sends the "post" to their inbox.

You can try it out here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

It has an example with the JS SDK so it should be easy to follow.